# Insertion/Deletion of account at an institution - AggCat API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

1:  If some account is actually deleted at an institution but is not deleted in AggCat service. What happens when Intuit pulls data from institutions to update accounts' info? The deleted account is not updated?

2:  If some account is added at an institution, how can we discover the newly added account? It seems the only feasible way is to remove all accounts of some client at that institution and have the client register accounts again. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, The deleted account doesn't get updated. If the account doesn't exist in FI, then that account should be categorized as 'Other Account'.
2. You can call discoverAndAddAccounts for that FI, and call UpdateInstitution login with refresh flag set to true. This will add refreshed data to the user's profile.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0020_discoverandaddaccounts